# Jquery code for show the preference text box when i click the group of check box

Tags: jquery, checkboxlist

i am creating a group of check box with same name, when i click one check box preference one(text box) is shown. or click two check box preference one and two will be show after that i unchecked the existing checked check box it will be show the preference one text box.
 how can i salve this problem..

my code is

```
<?php
 for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='sub_course' value='"$i.".>Sub course".$i;
 }
```

jquery code:

```
 `$('input[name=sub_course]').on('click',function(e){
    var courses = [];
    $.each($("input[name='sub_course']:checked"), function(){            
    courses.push($(this).val());
    });

    if(courses.length==1){
     $('#preference1').show();
    }else if(courses.length==2){
     $('#preference1').show();
     $('#preference2').show();
    }else{
     $('#preference1').hide();
     $('#preference2').hide();
   }
   });`
```

here #preference1 and #preference2 is textbox id

Comment: what's the problem you're having? Where do you get the error?

Comment: course.length==2 it shows two text boxes. but length goes to one from 2 it shows two check boxes. but i want to show one check box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to hide the other input here

```
if(courses.length==1){
    $('#preference1').show();
}
```

Like this:

```
if(courses.length==1){
    $('#preference1').show();
    $('#preference2').hide();
}
```